# How to take only last value from a list with unique tag?

Tags: python, list, filter, unique

In my LIST(not dictionary) I have these strings:

```
"K:60",
"M:37",
"M_4:47",
"M_5:89",
"M_6:91",
"N:15",
"O:24",
"P:50",
"Q:50",
"Q_7:89"
```

in output I need to have

```
"K:60",
"M_6:91",
"N:15",
"O:24",
"P:50",
"Q_7:89"
```

What is the possible decision?
Or even maybe, how to take tag with the maximum among strings with the same tag.

Comment: Why is "K:60" left out?

Comment: My mistake, add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as shown below. Use the fact that when the dictionary `dct` is created, only the *last* value is kept for each repeated key.

```
import re
lst = [
    "K:60",
    "M:37",
    "M_4:47",
    "M_5:89",
    "M_6:91",
    "N:15",
    "O:24",
    "P:50",
    "Q:50",
    "Q_7:89"
    ]

dct = dict([ (re.split(r'[:_]', s)[0], s) for s in lst])
lst_uniq = list(dct.values())
print(lst_uniq)
# ['K:60', 'M_6:91', 'N:15', 'O:24', 'P:50', 'Q_7:89']
```

Comment: Cool, thank u, maybe it is possible to do a dictionary from this? Where for instance, key is "K" and value is 60. Etc..

Comment: Use `{x.split(':')[0]:int(x.split(':')[1]) for x in a}` or `{x.split(':')[0].split('_')[0]:int(x.split(':')[1]) for x in a}`.

Comment: I dont understand) This way I use  dict_final = {}, than     for i in lst_uniq:
        elements = i.split(":",1)
        key = elements[0]
        val = elements[1]
        dict_final[key] = int(val)

Thanks anyway!)

Answer (score 0):

Probably far from the cleanest but here is a method quite easy to understand.

```
l = ["K:60", "M:37", "M_4:47", "M_5:89", "M_6:91", "N:15", "O:24", "P:50", "Q:50", "Q_7:89"]
reponse = []
val = []
complete_val = []
for x in l:
    if x[0] not in reponse:
        reponse.append(x[0])
        complete_val.append(x.split(':')[0])
        val.append(int(x.split(':')[1]))
    elif int(x.split(':')[1]) > val[reponse.index(x[0])]:
        val[reponse.index(x[0])] = int(x.split(':')[1])
for x in range(len(complete_val)):
    print(str(complete_val[x]) + ":" + str(val[x]))
```

```
K:60
M:91
N:15
O:24
P:50
Q:89
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any straight-forward technique. Other than iterating on entire thing and computing yourself, I do not see if any built-in can be used. I have written this where you do not require your values to be sorted in your input.

But I like the answer posted by Timur Shtatland, you can make us of that if your values are already sorted in input.

```
intermediate = {}
for item in a:
    key, val = item.split(':')
    key = key.split('_')[0]
    val = int(val)
    if intermediate.get(key, (float('-inf'), None))[0] < val:
        intermediate[key] = (val, item)
ans = [x[1] for x in intermediate.values()]
print(ans)
```

which gives:

```
['K:60', 'M_6:91', 'N:15', 'O:24', 'P:50', 'Q_7:89']
```

Comment: Then Timur's answer is best. Concise and clear.

Comment: Cool, it was a lucky break if so)!